# how to get field names from array of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My object like this

```
var obja = [{USER:"bob",  SCORE:2000, TIME:32,    AGE:16, COUNTRY:"US"},`{USER:"jane", SCORE:4000, TIME:35,    AGE:16, COUNTRY:"DE"},`{USER:"tim",  SCORE:1000, TIME:30,    AGE:17, COUNTRY:"UK"},` {USER:"mary", SCORE:1500, TIME:31,    AGE:19, COUNTRY:"PL"}];
```

but i want to store only fields USER,SCORE,TIME,AGE,COUNTRY in to array

Comment: uh, it already is an array? `[]` is array. you have an array of objects, which contain EXACTLY what you're asking for.

Comment: im trying to get only field names exactly, i want to bind drop down with field names like <option value='User'>User</option>

Comment: so, should they be a separate arrays of USERs, SCOREs, TIMEs , AGEs , COUNTRYs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an object keys this way

```js
var obja = [{USER:"bob",  SCORE:2000, TIME:32,    AGE:16, COUNTRY:"US"}, {USER:"jane", SCORE:4000, TIME:35,    AGE:16, COUNTRY:"DE"},{USER:"tim",  SCORE:1000, TIME:30,    AGE:17, COUNTRY:"UK"}, {USER:"mary", SCORE:1500, TIME:31,    AGE:19, COUNTRY:"PL"}];

for(var key  in obja[0]){ 
 console.log(key)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kid, its working...